# Qt Makefile won't find its own directory

Tags: c++, qt, include, makefile, qmake

I have downloaded the source of GoldenDict using Git, and run lrelease for the locales. Now I have a weird problem where I get this makefile log:

```
14:55:54: Running build steps for project goldendict...
14:55:54: Starting: "c:\qtsdk\desktop\qt\4.8.1\msvc2010\bin\qmake.exe" D:\GoldenDictSrc\goldendict\goldendict.pro -r -spec win32-msvc2010 "CONFIG+=release"
14:55:56: The process "c:\qtsdk\desktop\qt\4.8.1\msvc2010\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.
14:55:56: Starting: "C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Release
Error: dependent 'folding.cc' does not exist.
jom 1.0.8 - empower your cores

jom: D:\GoldenDictSrc\goldendict-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MSVC2010__Qt_SDK__Release\Makefile [release] Error 2
14:55:56: The process "C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building project goldendict (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'
```

while the file folding.cc is available in the same directory, in which the qmake file is.
I have even tried adding the absolute path of folding.cc to the qmake file, but no use.

I'm using QtCreator.

What can be causing this?

Thank you for any efforts.

Comment: have you moved the install after building it? I have had problems where qmake stored it's own path in the executable

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, and narrowed it down to the fact that QT only supports 122 characters for the path+filename of all dependent files (#includes or .cpp files).

If the path (relative or otherwise) is 123 characters or more, qt gives this error.

Just shorten your folder names, or filename to get the full path+filename to 122 characters or less.

Comment: To be more precise: winapi has problem with paths longer than 260 characters (see discussion [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-16443)). I guess you had 260+ chars in your absolute path...